# Qué significa el "total" que se imprime después de ejecutar ls -l

Tags: linux, centos

Disculpen por preguntar algo tan básico, pero al ejecutar:

```
$ ls -l
```

se imprime:

`total 4`

a pesar de que solo tengo 1 archivo dentro de ese directorio, entonces qué significa ese 4?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese valor `Total` corresponde al número de bloques de 1kB usados por los archivos en el directorio (sin revisar recursivamente en subdirectorios)

Comment: entendido, gracias